# Get NSTableCellView for a given row

Tags: nstableview

My `NSTableCellView` is subclassed and storing a pointer to an Object. I want to get access to that pointer and the only information I've got is the `row` number as `NSInteger`.

How do I access an `NSTableCellView` from my `tableView` with a given `row`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK got it:

```
NSTableCellView *selectedCell = [tableView viewAtColumn:selectedColumn
                                                    row:selectedRow 
                                        makeIfNecessary:NO];
```